# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined for $scope.search angular bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to write a function which filters rows based on couple of properties. When I run the code, the list is not getting displayed and there's an error stating "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined ". I am trying to search on columns name and location. Here's my html code

```
<tbody ng-if="routerList.length">
<tr ng-repeat="router in routerList | orderBy: rule|filter : search | limitTo:5:5*(naviagtion.currentPage-1) ">
    <td><span>{{router.routerId}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{router.name}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{router.macAddr}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{router.primaryIP}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{router.status}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{router.location}}</span></td> 

</tr>
</tbody>
```

In my controller, I have a function search

```
$scope.search = function(item){
    if($rootScope.naviagtion.searchText == undefined){
        return true;
    }else{
        if(item.router.name.indexOf($rootScope.naviagtion.searchText) != -1 || item.router.location.indexOf($rootScope.naviagtion.searchText) != -1 ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: you misspelled navigation `naviagtion`.

Comment: I know. The existing code has spelling naviagtion. It's not the problem

Comment: then the problem is probably at `item.router`. Can't read name cause .router is undefined?

Comment: It says cannot read property of name of undefined

Comment: Can you `console.log(item)`?

Answer (score 1):

The error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" means that there is a variable that has the dot operator on it that isn't defined.  Based on the code you posted it looks like the router is not defined.

```
router.name
```

A quick check in your if statement could resolve the issue.

```
if(item && item.router && ...) { }
```

If item.router is defined then it could be somewhere else in your code where you have some undefined object with a dot operator to a 'name' property.

```
someUndefinedObject.name
```

I usually use a debugger to make sure my object is in-fact defined when I see this error.